# Count and return the number of letters of each word in C

Tags: c, split, char, c-strings, function-definition

I'm learning C and I've created some small "challenges" for myself to solve. I have to create a program that reads an input string which consists of words separated by underscore and returns the last letter of each odd word followed by the number of chars of that word.

The input won't be empty. The words are separated by exactly 1 underscore. The first and last chars won't be underscores (so no `_this_is_a_sentence` or `this_is_a_sentence_` or `_this_is_a_sentence_`

**Example:**

input: `we_had_a_lot_of_rain_in_today`

output: `e2a1f2n2`

**Explanation:**

We only consider words in an odd position, so we just need to consider: `we`, `a`, `of` and `in`. Now, for each of those words, we get the last char and append the total number of chars of the word: `we` has 2 chars, so it becomes `e2`. `a` has 1 char, so it becomes `a1`, `of` has 2 chars so it becomes `f2` and `in` has 2 chars so it becomes `n2`.

This is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

void str_dummy_encrypt(char *sentence)
{
    int currentWord = 1;
    int totalChars = 0;
    for (int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (sentence[i] == '_')
        {
            if (currentWord % 2 != 0)
            {
                // I know the last char of the word is on sentence[i-1]
                // and the total chars for this word is totalChars
                // but how to return it in order to be printed?
            }
            currentWord++;
            totalChars = 0;
        } else {
            totalChars++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    while (scanf("%s", sentence) != EOF)
    {
        str_dummy_encrypt(sentence);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think I'm on the right path, but I don't have any clue on how to return the result to the main function so it can be printed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The expected output "e2a1o2i2" is unclear. For example why is there o2 instead of f2?

Comment: You're right, i'm very sorry. I've just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: As for your question then you need to allocate dynamically a character array and return it.

Comment: Aside: `scanf("%s", sentence)` ---> `scanf ("%99s", sentence)` to limit input.

Comment: Aside: the function needs to get the length of the last word when there are an odd number of words, which ends with `'\0'` not with `'_'`. The loop will end with a "dangling" word.

Comment: You could build a string into a buffer that is passed from `main`.

Comment: `scanf` is always filled with pitfalls, and for this particular problem you can structure the code to use only `getchar`.  It would also be a good exercise to take the input string from `argv`.

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right, nice catch. I will try to find a way to don't miss the last word

Comment: ...by concatening `"_"` to its end (make sure there's enough buffer space).

Answer (score 2):

> ... how to return the result (?)

You have a couple choices:

**Pass in the destination**

Caller provides an ample destination.

```
void str_dummy_encrypt(size_t dsize, char *destination, const char *sentence)
```

**Allocate and return the destination**

Caller should free the returned pointer when done.

```
char *str_dummy_encrypt(const char *sentence) {
  ...
  char *destination = malloc()
  ...
  return destination;
}
```

**Over-write the source**

This one is tricky as code needs to insure the destination does not get ahead of the source, but I think you are OK given the task requirements, as long as string length > 1.

```
void str_dummy_encrypt(char *sentence) {
  char *destination = sentence;
  ...
}
```

**Others**

---

Let us go deeper with *pass in the destination* and return a flag indicating success/error.

Use `snprintf()` to form the *letter-count*.

```
// Return error flag
int str_dummy_encrypt(size_t dsize, char *destination, const char *sentence) {
  ...
        if (currentWord % 2 != 0) {
          int len = snprintf(destination, dsize, "%c%d", sentence[i-1], totalChars);
          if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= dsize) {
            // We ran out of room
            return -1; // failure                  
          }
          // Adjust to append the next encoding.
          dsize -= len;
          destination += len;
        }
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

Usage

```
char sentence[100];
char destination[sizeof sentence + 1]; // I think worse case is 1 more than source.
...
    if (str_dummy_encrypt(sizeof destination, destination, sentence)) {
      puts("Error");
    } else {
      puts(destination);
    }
```

---

Code has other issues:

- Does not handle an odd number of *words* correctly like `"abc"`.
- Attempts `sentence[i-1]` with leading `_` like `"_abc"`.
- Poor input:

No width limit, weak test.

```
    char sentence[100];
    // while(scanf("%s", sentence) != EOF)
    while(scanf("%99s", sentence) == 1)
```

- Perhaps other issues.

---

Consider a test like `if(sentence[i+1] == '_' || sentence[i+1] == '\0')` to detect end of word and avoid 2 issues mentioned above.  (Count and other code will need adjusting too.)

Answer (score 2):

As it follows from the description of the task the function should return a new string that is built based on the fornat of the passed source string.

It means that you need to allocated dynamically a character array within the function where the result string will be stored.

As the source string is not changed within the function then the function parameter should have qualifier `const`.

And you should always write more general functions. This restriction

> The words are separated by exactly 1 underscore. The first and last
> chars won't be underscores (so no *this_is_a_sentence or
> this_is_a_sentence* or *this_is_a_sentence*

for the function does not make it general. The function should be able also to process strings like `"_this_is_a_sentence_"`.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * str_dummy_encrypt( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for (const char *p = s; *p; )
    {
        size_t length = 0;

        while (length == 0 && *p)
        {
            length = strcspn( p, "_" );
            if (length == 0) ++p;
        }

        if (length != 0)
        {
            p += length;
            n += 1 + snprintf( NULL, 0, "%zu", length );
        }

        length = 0;
        while (length == 0 && *p)
        {
            length = strcspn( p, "_" );
            p += length == 0 ? 1 : length;
        }
    }

    char *result = malloc( n + 1 );

    if (result != NULL)
    {
        result[n] = '\0';

        if (n != 0)
        {
            char *current = result;

            for (const char *p = s; *p; )
            {
                size_t length = 0;

                while (length == 0 && *p)
                {
                    length = strcspn( p, "_" );
                    if (length == 0) ++p;
                }

                if (length != 0)
                {
                    p += length;
                    *current++ = p[-1];
                    current += sprintf( current, "%zu", length );
                }

                length = 0;
                while (length == 0 && *p)
                {
                    length = strcspn( p, "_" );
                    p += length == 0 ? 1 : length;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "_we__had___a_lot_of_rain_in_today___";

    char *result = str_dummy_encrypt( s );

    if (result != NULL) puts( result );

    free( result );
}
```

The program output is

```
e2a1f2n2
```

The same output will be if to use the string showed in your question that is `"we_had_a_lot_of_rain_in_today"`.

The function would be more general if to add one more parameter that will specify the delimiter as

```
char * str_dummy_encrypt( const char *s, char c );
```

Or as the shown function implementation uses the standard C string function `strcspn` then the function could accept a set of delimiters like

```
char * str_dummy_encrypt( const char *s, const char *delimiters );
```

Comment: I totally agree. I've added the restrictions just to simplify a bit, but I totally agree that functions should prevent "extreme" situations.

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually need to read the word into a buffer, you can just read one character at a time and keep track of the last char, the word number and its length:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, lastc = ' ', n = 1, len = 0;
    for (;;) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == '_' || c == '\n' || c == EOF) {
            if (n & 1) {
                printf("%c%d", lastc, len);
            }
            n++;
            len = 0;
            if (c != '_')
                break;
        } else {
            lastc = c;
            len++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```